# How to crop image of size as the height - width of device?

Tags: android

I want to crop image which has height-width same as any device.
I tried following code to crop image, code is working but image size is not same as device height width.
Can any body guide me?

```
        Display mDisplay = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        int outX    =  Utility.dpToPx(mDisplay.getWidth(), displayMetrics);
        int outY    =  Utility.dpToPx(mDisplay.getHeight(), displayMetrics);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", mDisplay.getWidth());    
        intent.putExtra("outputY", mDisplay.getHeight());
        intent.putExtra("scale", "true");
        intent.putExtra("return-data", "false");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
        intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.toString());
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by changing values of aspectX and aspectY fields as following

```
intent.putExtra("aspectX", mDisplay.getWidth());
intent.putExtra("aspectY", mDisplay.getHeight());
```

and commented following two lines

```
//intent.putExtra("outputX", mDisplay.getWidth());    
//intent.putExtra("outputY", mDisplay.getHeight());
```